# Mesa update has caused problems

Tags: drivers, 16.04, updates, graphics, mesa

I recently updated mesa using the method:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update`

However since the update certain things have stopped working, for example the gnome terminal, Firefox download window, and shut down options do not who up despite being open, there is a shadow but that is it.
I have also become incapable of locking the screen at all, whether through a keyboard shortcut or through the menu.

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help, I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with an Intel processor, thank you.

Comment: If Mesa 13 try Mesa 12? If Mesa 12 try Mesa 13? Sorry can't help much just read a little about Vulkan is all....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a somewhat simple problem to solve.
I downgraded mesa to the version that came with Ubuntu 16.04 by using
`sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`
Rebooted and everything was fixed.